# Node.js application structure

Tags: node.js, architecture, structure, organization

In my Node.js app, I have a folder for API, Lib, and Utils in addition to Server.js and app.js files.
Is there a structure that is best for a Node Application that makes multiple api calls to different endpoints? I'm struggling with how to best organize the code in my applcation.

Comment: There are dozens of possible strategies for laying out your project.  Some are more natural with certain architectures (such as model, view, controller) than others.  None are "right" and none are "wrong".  There are just lots of opinions.  So, there is no real "answer" to your question, just lots of different possibilities to consider so you can pick what feels natural to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder structure for your application is already a step in the correct path!
Use an app layer, controller, service, and data access layer for your application. Ensure you name your folders so it's readable. Check out this article for more details - https://blog.logrocket.com/the-perfect-architecture-flow-for-your-next-node-js-project/

One common setup is to have the entry points/initiators call services to do the heavy-lifting work, so you could have a top-level directory called that.  This is definitely common at Directly.  The two top-level services that stand out would be directlyService.js and stackOverflowService.js (or forumService.js or some other non-vendor-specific name).  Those two services could call other services (hopefully there are obvious groupings of the other business processes) to subdivide processing further.